# Remove the Null Value from the result generated from MAX() used in query sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

When i use the query:

```
select MAX(DT_LOGDATE)
from   UMS_LOGENTRY_DTL
where  C_INPUTMODE='R' and VC_DEVICEID=10
```

the table gives maximum date, but if the condition is not satisfied it returns a data table with NULL. so there will be a null row. But I need it as empty data table. How I remove that null on noresult?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use HAVING clause:

```
SELECT MAX(DT_LOGDATE)
FROM   UMS_LOGENTRY_DTL
WHERE  C_INPUTMODE='R' and VC_DEVICEID=10
HAVING MAX(DT_LOGDATE) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: That's a nice one, I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 4):

Use a derived table and filter on that:

```
select *
from (
  select MAX(DT_LOGDATE) as max_date
  from   UMS_LOGENTRY_DTL
  where  C_INPUTMODE='R' 
  and VC_DEVICEID=10
) t
where max_date is not null
```

Comment: I just curious, why you want to write in the () instead of adding the where statement?

Comment: @Y.Z.: because you can't reference an alias directly in the `where` clause. The derived table is needed for syntax reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Scalar aggregates always return a single row even if aggregating an empty set.

You can also do

```
SELECT MAX(DT_LOGDATE)
FROM   UMS_LOGENTRY_DTL
WHERE  C_INPUTMODE = 'R'
       AND VC_DEVICEID = 10 
GROUP BY ()
```

The `GROUP BY` clause makes it a [vector aggregate rather than scalar](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/03/12/fun-with-aggregates.aspx) and no `NULL` row will be returned if there are no rows in `UMS_LOGENTRY_DTL` that match the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your query as a subquery and add another condition:

```
select max_date
from
(
    select MAX(DT_LOGDATE) max_date
    from   UMS_LOGENTRY_DTL
    where  C_INPUTMODE='R' and VC_DEVICEID=10
) sub
where sub.max_date is not null
```